# What's the minimum system requirements need to run Tomcat+Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I need a virtual dedicated server or java hosting for my portfolio web-applications by Java(It means < 10 online users). If I buy a VDS 300Mhz, 256 RAM, can I run Tomcat and Mysql, or Glassfish, or I not? Whats a minimum requirements? How I can calculate thtm for 100, 1000 users?

Answer (score 3):

This is too small for running nearly anything involving a Java servlet container and a database. And it all depends on what your application does and how it's implemented anyway. Load-test your application with the expected number of users, see if it works, measure the response times, and choose your settings accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

256 MB RAM VDS will be too small to run Java and related products. Basically, if you buy a VDS with a optimized control panel like WHM/CPanel, 92 to 100 MB RAM will be default consumed by CP & OS. So, you will hardly have 150 MB RAM to Run JAVA & your applications.

I recommend you to start with 512 MB RAM VPS server. Go for a Cloud Server which is instantly scalable. A cloud with 512 MB RAM will hardly cost you $20 to $25 per month. I am running some of my 24 x 7 hoovers on a [512 MB linux clouds](http://www.accuwebhosting.com/linux-cloud.html).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there's a minimum requirement, but 256 RAM would not be enough for anything bigger. Currently running my app on 600 MB RAM with MySQL and Tomcat, and it's barely sufficient.

You can simulate that by giving your local Tomcat `Xmx128m` and `XX:PermGenSize=64m` (leaving the rest to MySQL and the OS), and preform JMeter tests with 100 users.